# CSS: Position: absolute; causes input element to move on input in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a search box inside a grid, but for some reason, the input box jumps almost to the other side of the page when a user starts typing in it. I've narrowed it down and found out that the `position: absolute` causes this. This only happens in Chrome. What's wrong with the code?

CSS:

```
header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15% 50% 30% 5%;
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    margin-left: 26.5%;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    position: relative;
}

header input {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.searchStyle {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 75px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    top: 21%;
}

.searchStyle:focus {
    width: 200px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BA9765;
    outline: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
    [other code]

    <input class="searchStyle" type="text" placeholder="SEARCH…" id="search-bar" />
    [other code]
</header>
```

[Here's the issue in Chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnLmP.png)

[Here's what it should look like (Firefox).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVtjC.png)

Comment: Question: why exactly are you using grid-template but then absolutely position an element? I'm not saying that's necessarily a bad thing, just curious about the rationale behind your code.

Comment: Not an expert in CSS yet, so I don't know if it's the optimal solution, but I wanted to align the input field to the right side inside the grid column and then make it expand with an animation towards left when focused. Without position: absolute it expands towards right instead, which I don't want.

Comment: It's 2022 - and I see this excact behavior in Chrome 103 ... any explanation or fix?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find out why position: absolute causes this in Chrome, but manage to find a solution by removing the position absolute, put the input inside a div and make a class for that div with these values:

```
.gridAlign {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```